# Angular 8 - calling observables sequentially

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying calling several observables one after another. Here is my code:

```
 // service1    
 login(username: string, password: string): any {
  this.service2.firstObservable(username, password)
    .pipe(map(
      data => {
          if (data) {
            return this.service2.secondObservable(data, username, password)
            .subscribe(token => {
              return true;
            });
          }
      },
      error => {
          this.service.error(error);
          return false;
      }
    ));
}
```

Execution:

```
this.service1.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
    .pipe(map(
      data => {
          // Login is successful 
      }
    ));
```

I get:

```
Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
```

Obviously service1.login returns a wrong value. Is it possible to make something this working?

Thanks

Update 1.

```
login(username: string, password: string): any {
  return this.service1.firstObservable(username, password)
    .pipe(switchMap(
      data => this.service1.secondObservable(data, username, password)
    ));
}
```

Comment: Could you also share the part where you use that login function? Also, could you check if the request to the server is actually made and what it is returning?

Comment: < login function> It is in my original post under Execution. You are correct about the backend. Something is not right. It worked fine. Need to investigate.

Comment: if the login function is still the same as it is in your original post, you are not subscribing to the observable, so none of the code in it will be executed.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, after subscribing to it it started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try switchMap to switch observables, and remember to return the value in service1:

```
login(username: string, password: string): any {
  return this.service2.firstObservable(username, password)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(
        data => this.service2.secondObservable(data, username, password)
      ),
      catchError(
        error => {
          this.service.error(error);
          return throw(error); // In case you want to catch it later
        }
      )
    );
}
```

After that the second piece of code should work.

Comment: I get: switchMap is deprecated: resultSelector is no longer supported, use inner map instead

Comment: That's odd. What version of rxjs are you using? Are you importing it like this? `import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: Like this: import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'; "rxjs": "^6.5.2",

Comment: The only thing I found regarding your problem is you might be passing two arguments to the switchMap pipe? I have never seen that error before and switchMap is definitely not deprecated.

Comment: Yes, removing second parameter helped. But when I runt I get:Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined at the line: this.service1.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)

Comment: Sorry. Even though I mentioned you should return the observable I didn't return it myself in the code snippet. I edited it, notice in the second line of the snippet you need to return the observable.

Comment: Still is not working. I am not getting any errors anymore, but the execution is not reaching line: data => ..

Comment: Are you subscribing to it? You can try adding a second function in the subscribe to see whether it throws any errors... If not try to update the original question so I can see the updated version of your code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `await`, but then method must be `void` and `asnyc`

```
    async login(username: string, password: string) {
        let data = await this.service2.firstObservable(username, password).toPromise();
        if(data){
            let data2: boolean = await this.service2.secondObservable(data, username, password).toPromise();
        }
    }
```

Comment: pipe is not a function at the line: this.service1.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)

Comment: Why would you want to do this? it's time to think reactive in our Angular apps, that's why RxJS exist to make our life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to concatenate sequential requests:

```
 login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
  this.service2.firstObservable(username, password)
    .pipe(flatMap(
      (data) => {
          if (data) {
            return this.service2.secondObservable(data, username, password).pipe(flatMap((token) => {return true;}))
          }
      },
      error => {
          this.service.error(error);
          return false;
      }
    ));
}
```

Comment: A couple of problems. A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value. Argument of type '(token: boolean) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: boolean, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'. I also had to remove error handler to avoid deprecated as it was described above.